# Equivalent in Octave to Matlab's fittype function

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting

I have some matlab code that I want to run in Octave. There's a function that does not work for octave, which is fittype. I have been googleing to find equivalent functions in Octave but to no avail.

I will post the code of that function to clarify the issue.

```
function bn = createFit2(b8,bi)

% --- Plot data that was originally in data set "bi vs. b8"
b8 = b8(:);
bi = bi(:);

% --- Create fit "fit"
ok_ = isfinite(b8) & isfinite(bi);
if ~all( ok_ )
warning( 'GenerateMFile:IgnoringNansAndInfs',...
    'Ignoring NaNs and Infs in data.' );
end
ft_ = fittype('poly1');

% Fit this model using new data
cf_ = fit(b8(ok_),bi(ok_),ft_);

bn = cf_.p1;

% disp(cf_.p1)
```

Comment: Tell us what exactly you want to achieve. You might be interested in `polyfit`, `polyval`, etc.

Comment: As I stated in my comments to am304 answer, my only objective is to transform an MatLab script (actually 2) into Octave and make them work exactly the same, or yield the same results, in order to convince the staff to stay away from the expensive Matlab and have an alternative that works.

Comment: I am trying with polyfit which is seeming to work well, though I am not sure how to match the properties of the MAtlab fitobject cf_ I have in my code. I found that polyfit yields a vector of dimension 3. Not sure the first component matches the p1 property I have in the matlab code (bn = cf_.p1)

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Curve Fitting Toolbox and I doubt you will find an equivalent for Octave. However, because you are trying to fit a first-order polynomial, it is rather straightforward to write the fitting by hand (you are only looking for the two polynomial coefficients), or even use the [`polyfit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Polynomial-Interpolation.html) function.

Comment: Thankyou am304, I will try to have polyfit doing the trick. I am not very good at fitting but have some background. As the purpose of this translation is just try to convince my boss for migrating from MatLab I have to make this function work. The company asked a University dept. to solve a remote sensing problem and some of the things they came up with was this function. If I can make it work in Octave, my chances will increase quite a lot. I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code.
It is not giving me the same results but, I am still trying to understand what I am doing and what the output parameters are. 
There's the line bn=cf_.p1 in the matlab code. I assume is the property p1 of the object cf_, of the class fitobject.

```
function bn = createFit2(b8,bi)
% --- Plot data that was originally in data set "bi vs. b8"
b8 = b8(:);
bi = bi(:);
% --- Create fit "fit"
ok_ = isfinite(b8) & isfinite(bi);
if ~all( ok_ )
    warning( 'GenerateMFile:IgnoringNansAndInfs',...
        'Ignoring NaNs and Infs in data.' );
end
ft_ = 1 %orden del polinomio
% Fit this model using new data
cf_ = polyfit(b8(ok_),bi(ok_),ft_);
bn = cf_(1);
cf_ %muestra el valor de cf cada vez que ejecuta la función
% disp(cf_.p1)
```

My research is now on figuring which of the octave output is equivalent to the p1 from the cf_ MatLab fitobject.

Trial and error method showed me that indeed cf_.1 is cf_(1) in the resulting vector from fitting function fit (Matlab) and polyfit(Octave). The other thing I figured out was the polynomial orther was 1 instead of 2, wich I wasn't aware of.

Thanks all for your advices. You put me on the right track.